# Php+Mysql, order by id + start with specific id

Tags: php, mysql

```
ID | NAME
1  | yassine
2  | yask
3  | oisus
4  | iouosiud
5  | iouous
```

> $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC");

what i want to do is that i want to start with 3 . It should output like this:

3,1,2,4,5.

is it possible ?

Comment: you always want to start with 3 (regardless of number of records) or the one in between?

Comment: Yes i want to start 3 (regardless of number of records)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id=3 DESC, id ASC
```

Arranged the list using `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

`` SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY (id=3) ASC ``
No need to use union!

Comment: It doesnt affect the query, however thank you so much for your effort